# PHP: how to access variables inside a function that have been declared outside of it?

Tags: php, function, include, visibility

At the very beginning of each page I include a file that starts the SESSION etc, lets call it `session.php`. In this file `session.php`, I include a file that contains a function, let's call it `function1.php`, because I need the function to be available in `session.php`.

However, later in the main page I also include `function2.php` which needs to access variables set in `session.php`, so I additionally tried to include `session.php` in `function2.php`.

The problem is that an error occurs as function1 will be declared multiple times...

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function1() (previously declared in ...

So, what would be a more elegant and clean(er) solution for this? How could you solve it?

Basically, I'd need to access variables inside a function that have been included in the main page before...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't an issue with public and private variables, since the variables you want from session.php aren't part of an object. They're just variables which you declared (probably) in the global scope, and now need to access in function2.php.

First: are the contents of function2.php... a function? If not, then that file should have the same scope as the location in your script from which it was included, and it should be able to access them just fine.

If the place from which you need to access the session.php variables is a function, or an object, you have a few choices.

**0. Re-include the file**

This is what you're trying to do now. It fails because session.php also contains a function definition and you can't re-define a function once it's been created. As a workaround, you could move the variable definitions into a separate file and just include that in function2. This is clumsy, but simple.

**1. Pass the variables to the function when you call it.**

- Pros: simple and flexible.
- Cons: Makes calling the function kind of a pain. You could simplify this by putting them all into a single array of parameters, rather than passing each separately.

**2. Use `global`**

At the beginning of function2, just add the command `global $var1, $var2 ...` to import any variables that were used elsewhere in the script.

This is also very simple, but using global variables is seen by many programmers as sloppy and opens you up to hard-to-debug errors elsewhere.

**3. Use constants**

In session.php, define the variables you want to share as constants. e.g., `define("PASSWORD", "coolpassword123")`. Constants can be referenced from inside functions or objects, etc., and can never be changed after being declared. e.g., `echo(PASSWORD)` (no quotes, no $).

Constants are generally the best solution to this kind of problem as long as 1) you don't need to change their value, and 2) you can stick to simple numeric or string values. A constant can't be an array, object, etc.

Comment: wow, thank you octern! That is an awesome explanation! Thanks for the great and well explained insight! :)

Answer (score 2):

try `include_once` instead of `include`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

EDIT:
Complete example

**main.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'session.php';
include 'function2.php';
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'function1.php';
function1('session.php');
```

**function1.php**

```
<?php
function function1($calledFrom)
{
    echo 'function1 called from: ' . $calledFrom . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**function2.php**

```
include_once 'function1.php';
function1('function2.php');
```

Put these all in the same folder and run

```
php main.php
```

The output is:

> function1 called from: session.php
>
> function1 called from: function2.php

Comment: have tried that, as suggested in another SO post, does not work... but thx!

Comment: are you using include_once in all places?

Comment: well, twice... once for session.php which includes function1.php and then function2.php includes session.php (and therefore function1.php again...)

Comment: include_once() _prevents_ the include file from being included a second time. This solves problems with functions being redeclared and so forth, but it doesn't solve the problem of being able to access those values from within function2.php.

Comment: @octern: so, is there a possibility to access those values from within function2.php?

Comment: once a file has been included the functions are available from anywhere; take a peak at the example code I just added.

Comment: @quickshiftin: yes, thank you... I am just confused: the functions are available, but what about the variables defined in session.php? They are not available inside function1() in function1.php...

Comment: Yes, I just posted an answer with some options.

Comment: variables are a little different, take a look at @octern's answer

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you aren't using the same name for functions across files that will be included.

After that, you can simply pass the variable in question as a parameter for the function

```
function1($variable1);
```

then retrieve it in the function

```
function function1($getvar){
    //do something with the passed variable $getvar
}
```